# How to extract Strings from DataGrid regardless of what type contains in GWT

Tags: gwt, datagrid, exporter

I'am programming a generic DataGrid to Excel exporter. What I wanted to do is to extract an ArrayList which represents the rows, and for each row I have an array of Colomn. So basically,  I want to extract an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

The DataGrid have some methods as `dataGrid.getColumn(i)` or `dataGrid.getRowElement(i)` but I couldn't find anything to get a String from a specific cell(row,col).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
dataGrid.getRowElement(i).getCells().getItem(j);
```

You would have to write a method to extract all the data and put it in your ArrayList>. Maybe something like that (please note this code was written without any IDE):

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGrid.getRowCount(); i++){
  TableRowElement element = dataGrid.getRowElement(i);
  for(int j = 0; j < element.getCells().getLenght(); j++){
    list.add(element.getCells().getItem(j).toString();
  }
}
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: That's exactly what I'am looking for. Thx